# Problems with SwiftUI not redrawing views

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Working on my first SwiftUI project, and as I started moving some of my more complex views into their own view structs I started getting problems with the views not being redrawn.

As an example, I have the following superview:

```
struct ContainerView: View {

    @State var myDataObject: MyDataObject?
    
    var body: some View {
        if let myDataObject = myDataObject {
            TheSmallerView(myDataObject: myDataObject)
                .padding(.vertical, 10)
                .frame(idealHeight: 10)
                .padding(.horizontal, 8)
                .onAppear {
                    findRandomData()
                }
        }
        else {
            Text("No random data found!")
                .onAppear {
                    findRandomData()
                }
        }
        
    }

    private func findRandomData() {
        myDataObject = DataManager.shared.randomData
    }
}
```

Now when this first gets drawn I get the Text view on screen as the myDataObject var is nil, but the .onAppear from that gets called, and myDataStruct gets set with an actual struct. I've added breakpoints in the body variable, and I see that when this happens it gets called again and it goes into the first if clause and fetches the "TheSmallerView" view, but nothing gets redrawn on screen. It still shows the Text view from before.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: Here's the relevant parts of TheSmallerView:

```
struct TheSmallerView: View {

    @ObservedObject var myDataObject: MyDataObject
```

EDIT2: Fixed the code to better reflect my actual code.

Comment: Does `findRandomData()` change the value of `myDataStruct`?

Comment: Yep. Initially it goes from nil to storing a struct. Then on subsequent onAppear (from the Text view) it sets it to new structs. Again, body gets called and it goes into the if clause and fetched the TheSmallerView view, but it isn't displayed on screen.

Comment: what does TheSmallerView contain ?

Comment: A whole bunch of views. It was extracted from ContainerView as it shared a lot of code with another view.

Comment: Can you share the snippet of `TheSmallerView` how you have declared `myDataStruct` variable?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it — maybe it has to do with how `MyDataStruct` or `DataManager` is implemented?

Comment: if you replace your data struct with a simple random number, and replace TheSmallerView  with a text to show random number your logic works, there should be something about TheSmallerView/ shared random data/ DataStruct

Comment: Added in the relevant parts from the subview.

Comment: will myDataStruct gets changed within TheSmallerView ? if not, it doesnt have to be a ObservedObject. If myDataStruct changes, your TheSmallerView gets recreated.

Comment: There is a lot wrong with your code but without a full example it is impossible to tell

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring `@Binding var myDataStruct: MyDataStruct` inside the `TheSmallerView` view and pass it like this: `TheSmallerView(myDataStruct: $myDataStruct)` from `ContainerView`

Comment: Unfortunately it's an optional in ContainerView, and not an optional in TheSmallerView.

Comment: That's why it's not getting redrawn, because the state of your myDataStruct changes, but the child view does not know it changes because you are not passing the State property obeserver.
 TheSmallerView(myDataStruct: myDataStruct) here you are only passing the value

Comment: But the child view doesn't even get created until it has changed in ContainerView.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You are using [`@ObservedObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/observedobject) in the subview, but that property wrapper is only for classes (and your data is a struct).</s>

You can use [`@State`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state/) instead (b/c the data is a struct).

**Edit:**
The data isn't a struct.
Because it is a class, you should use [`@StateObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject/) instead of `@State`.

Comment: Sorry, in my rush to anonymise the code I ended up turning my NSManagedObject into a struct.  Fixed it in the original post now.

Comment: But I can't use that on an optional, correct?

Comment: I think you can, if the object conforms to `ObservableObject` (but I'm not 100% sure — I've never tried).

Comment: `@State` definitely doesn't work if you're using an object.

Comment: `@State` is a "right" way of initializing an `ObservableObject`, it was a common practice before the availability of `StateObject`. You will see changes to the entire object but not changes to the variables. The OP is omitting a lot of code it isn't really possible to diagnose with what we can see.

Answer (score 0):

In lack of complete code I created this simple example based on OPs code, which works fine the way it is expected to. So the problem seems to be somewhere else.

```
class MyDataObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var number: Int
    
    init() {
        number = Int.random(in: 0...1000)
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {

    @State var myDataObject: MyDataObject?
    
    var body: some View {
        if let myDataObject = myDataObject {
            TheSmallerView(myDataObject: myDataObject)
                .onAppear {
                    findRandomData()
                }
        }
        else {
            Text("No random data found!")
                .onAppear {
                    findRandomData()
                }
        }
    }

    private func findRandomData() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            myDataObject = MyDataObject()
        }
    }
}

struct TheSmallerView: View {

    @ObservedObject var myDataObject: MyDataObject
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("The number is: \(myDataObject.number)")
    }
}
```